# How to automatically update values for some employees in mvc

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I selected employees need to quit the job in 31-Jan-2019

```
IDbg | name  | status | Quitdate
-----+-------+--------+-------------
 123 | Kally | Active | 31-Jan-2019
 222 | Shan  | Active | 31-Jan-2019
 845 | Danny | Active | 31-Jan-2019
```

How to automatically update `Status` values at this date?

Change status (active to inactive) in ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: Update when ? On what event ?

Comment: Yes on event 31-Jan-2018

Comment: You can create console application to update the status, which can be schedule to run each day say 12:00AM.

Comment: I created PROCEDURE

Comment: console application to update the status?

Comment: you can use trigger as well to auto update data